# github copilot giving away API keys? how can I protect my keys?

Tags: javascript, security, visual-studio-code

I have installed and used github copilot for some time. And while working on a google maps project, I was curious and asked it to autocomplete the API url with the key open, and it listed suggestions with various API keys included. This got me worried since it generates codes based on other people code on github.

[image]

At first I was thinking those could be not functional keys, But I found that to be wrong based on [this](https://fossbytes.com/github-copilot-generating-functional-api-keys/) article.

So, how what methods can I use to protect my keys from such happening?
I am thinking uninstalling wont help since my repos are already at github.

Comment: Do not check your api keys into git and you are safe :) should not do do this regardless of copilot existing or not.

Comment: The best practice is to not commit API keys to your repo. I should note however that this advice is not often listened to in corporate environments. API keys should always be read from a config file and you should never commit your config files along with your code (you may not think this separation is necessary but there may be a time when you will want to share or sell your code to other people and now they have access to your API keys in the git history)

Comment: But arent API keys such as google map's are going to be always publicly shown on the frontend? just like in many other big pages, and only protected by security options such as refere restriction...? But google copilot might also list unprotected API keys

Comment: Ah, you have committed the SECOND sin of API keys. API keys **should never be used in the frontend**. People often wonder why there is no solution to the CORS problem when accessing 3rd party APIs but this is on purpose - the 3rd parties don't want you to expose the API keys thus not enabling CORS which forces you to use their API in your backend which will protect API keys (so long as your server is not hacked). Write your own private API endpoints on your server and have your server make the request to 3rd party APIs. Your server should be the only thing that can read the API keys

Comment: @slebetman thank you, but isn't it the way google recommends on their doc for google map? to include the API key in the `<script>` tag src, like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap` on the google map [doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#maps_map_simple-javascript)

Comment: Note that in some strict environments like HIPPA and/or ISO 27001 developers are not supposed to have access to things like API keys used by your app. Only sysadmins (who cannot be the same person as the developer) can have access to configuration data. But generally this only applies if your product need to be compliant like if your website manage medical or banking data.

Comment: @slebetman if you want to embed Google Maps in your application, you need the API key to be included in the frontend code. As far as I know, there is no way around that.

Comment: Yeah. Google map may be low risk since you are not managing any 3rd party data. Only map locations. So there is little risk exposing Google Map API keys from google's point of view (from your point of view the risk is a script kiddie finding your keys and abusing it and getting you throttled or banned - but that's not google's risk). For other things like Facebook login etc. (which actually give you access to other peoples data) you should not expose API keys to the frontend.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to protect yourself is to not commit any private information to a public git repository.

Your Google Maps API key should be stored in an environment variable or a configuration file, and should never be checked into git.

A common way to do this for modern applications is to use environment variables in production and a `.env` file in development (that simulates using environment variables but actually holds the content of those variables in a local file). There are "dotenv" libraries available for just about every programming language. You will typically also create a `.env.example` file ***which you do commit to git*** that contains examples of all of the environment variables that your application requires, but does not contain actual secret values.

Comment: Personally I'd extend this advice to ALL repositories public or private. Private repositories are usually used for commercial code and when you want to sell your code to clients you now have the problem of the client having access to your API keys in the git history or you are forced to sell the code without git history (which some clients may insist on having)

Comment: But arent API keys such as google map's going to be always publicly shown on the frontend? just like in many other big pages, and only protected by security options such as refere restriction...? But google copilot might also list unprotected API keys for everyone

Comment: @Abraham Yes, Google Maps isn't really such a good example because the API key is visible to anyone who does a View Source on your page. Google does rely on the referer header to prevent other people from using your key, but it's not foolproof. However, there are many other types of API keys or other configuration data that should never be committed to git, and best practices suggest that you should be consistent in how you handle configuration.

Comment: @slebetman, I think the best solution at that point is just to delete the api key and make a new one which you manage properly.

Comment: Sorry, but how would this prevent co-pilot from knowing your API keys? To provide you with answers, co-pilot obviously sends your code to the Github backend to be able to provide contextual answers. Your key will, most likely, be accessible by your code IDE and thus, by extension, co-pilot... You must simply just TRUST that co-pilot does not store this somewhere or use it for further learning!

Comment: @DanieleTesta The question is asking about Copilot's responses which are built by an AI model ***that is trained from publicly available code on GitHub that included API keys in it***. The questioner was asking about how to prevent API keys from becoming part of the training dataset, not about the Copilot lookup API.

Comment: @MosheKatz And you honestly don't think that the model gets trained/tweaked continuously based on the data that the co-pilot collects? Co-pilot automatically uploads your code to their backend together with your question to be able to generate a good response. How else would it be able to include the variable names etc that you are already using in your code? Because it knows it! Who says they are not storing that data/code to use for future model training? Your keys will be included there! That's what he wants to prevent.

Comment: @DanieleTesta If what you are saying is correct, then it would definitely be unsafe to use tools like Copilot - and it's not a question of TRUST. Clearly there are existing API keys in the copilot training data, that's how the original questioner was able to see them suggested. If everything you type immediately gets added to the model, then there would be absolutely no way to prevent Copilot from suggesting your API keys to other users.

Comment: I also don't believe it would make sense to train the model on a user's typing, because there are bound to be a lot more errors in code that is currently being worked on vs. code that is committed to a repository. Why would you want to train your model on work in progress?

Comment: I never said they immediately train on your data. But they GET your data. What they do with it, is to their discretion. And YES, that is the whole problem! It IS very unsafe to use products like co-pilot! That's why many companies have banned their developers from using them. You have no control of what actually gets sent to their servers together with your prompts. Example: https://the-decoder.com/apple-bans-chatgpt-and-copilot-works-on-own-language-models/

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a functional API key from CoPilot, and they are often /the wrong length/ to boot, my personal experience suggest that

### CoPilot scrambles and crops API keys.

If you've ever gotten an actually functionl API key from CoPilot, I'd love to hear your story though.